# How to see all exception in Visual Studio WPF before compiling?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have worked in ASP.NET MVC before, If I set to BuildView = true, it show me error in my .cshtml  file when I  compile.

I am new to WPF and this is the problem from last few days. I just integrate code from another project, some control, image and style.

Now I run the app, take it to the page and it's crash, It say this is missing. missing style and image. I fix one by one issue and it's take a lot of time.

Is there anyway I can got all these error when I compile. I am fixing one by one error and compiling. Is there a better way to sort out this.
[image]

Comment: WPF is really really hard to debug (namely those xaml parsing errors). The compile time errors are the easiest, simply open "Output" window (there is a setting to open it automatically on build) and look there. If you successfully build try open a certain xaml - you will get errors immediately. The run-time errors are a different "painful" story. Sometimes errors are very misleading, like that one with "cannot find resource". The best tactic is to observe (undo?) most recent changes, to see difference between "it was working" and "now it doesn't work". The mistake is there.

Comment: @Sinatr The good part is I can see the lines on images, styles in .xaml file when I open it. The worst part is VS 2017 lie that something is error and clearly not telling me what is wrong. It's working good in 2015. I open 2015 to fix my issues and coding in 2017.